# MVC 5 - Show custom database calculated field using EF Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a SQL Server database. Then used MVC 5 to generate model from it. I used scaffolding to create my controller and view. Now I am not sure how can I display a new field based on record count from another child table. I basically want to display child count for a parent record. Or I want to run any kind of SQL query and display result next to a record. Any link to tutorial will be very helpful. Thank You.

Comment: Showing some code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there must be much better way to do this. But for now I found this solution. Hopefully someone can put much better solution here. In example below I have table customer where each record is assigned to a location from table CustLoc. Here i am attempting to show CustLoc records and also count of customer for each location.

So here are steps I did.

1. Enter a new field in Model class.

> public string CustCount { get; set; }

2. Now in controller write this.

> ```
> public ActionResult Index()
> {
>   foreach(var CustLoc in db.CustLocs)
>   {
>     CustLoc.CustCount = CustLoc.CustomerInfoes.Count().ToString();
>   }
>   return View(db.CustLoc.ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder));
> }
> ```

3. Now display the new field in view

> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustCount)

Thanks.